# Skip NA values using "FUN=first"

Tags: r, function, dataframe

there's probably really an simple explaination as to what I'm doing wrong, but I've been working on this for quite some time today and I still can not get this to work. I thought this would be a walk in the park, however, my code isn't quite working as expected.

So for this example, let's say I have a data frame as followed.

```
df
Row#   user      columnB    
1        1          NA        
2        1          NA        
3        1          NA        
4        1          31        
5        2          NA        
6        2          NA        
7        2          15        
8        3          18        
9        3          16       
10       3          NA
```

Basically, I would like to create a new column that uses the first (**as well as last**) function (within the TTR library package) to obtain the first non-NA value for each user. So my desired data frame would be this.

```
df
Row#   user      columnB    firstValue
1        1          NA        31
2        1          NA        31 
3        1          NA        31
4        1          31        31
5        2          NA        15
6        2          NA        15 
7        2          15        15
8        3          18        18
9        3          16        18
10       3          NA        18
```

I've looked around mainly using google, but I couldn't really find my exact answer.

Here's some of my code that I've tried, but I didn't get the results that I wanted (note, I'm bringing this from memory, so there are quite a few more variations of these, but these are the general forms that I've been trying).

```
    df$firstValue<-ave(df$columnB,df$user,FUN=first,na.rm=True)
    df$firstValue<-ave(df$columnB,df$user,FUN=function(x){x,first,na.rm=True})
    df$firstValue<-ave(df$columnB,df$user,FUN=function(x){first(x,na.rm=True)})
    df$firstValue<-by(df,df$user,FUN=function(x){x,first,na.rm=True})
```

Failed, these just give the first value of each group, which would be NA.

Again, these are just a few examples from the top of my head, I played around with na.rm, using na.exclude, na.omit, na.action(na.omit), etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also, here are some websites which I referenced help from. 

http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/06/09/1294.html 
http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/113478.html
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/missing.htm

Comment: Ah, I apologize, it was actually those extra html links that were acting funny. Anyways, I've added the text. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment when I saw your edit. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: Note that you should replace all the `na.rm=True` with `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: Haven't tested, but (following @Arun's now-deleted answer): `ddply(df, .(user), transform, firstValue=ifelse(is.na(columnB),NA,na.omit(columnB)[1]))` ?

Comment: Good catch, but I still tried that earlier, (in addition with also just using T), but to no avail.

Comment: That looks good for catching the first value and I'll try that tomorrow, so thanks for that. But I would also like to see how to capture the last value as well. Could we attach a negative sign somewhere in there to reverse it?

Comment: @BenBolker, yes, I deleted it to modify the code to add the result as an extra column, before which juba provided a much nicer solution using `transform` like yours.

Comment: The main problem is that `first`/`last` don't have built-in `na.rm` arguments, so you have to use something like `na.omit()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.table` solution

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key="user")
DT[, firstValue := na.omit(columnB)[1], by=user]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `plyr` :

```
ddply(df, .(user), transform, firstValue=na.omit(columnB)[1])
```

Which gives :

```
  Row user columnB firstValue
1   1    1      NA         31
2   2    1      NA         31
3   3    1      NA         31
4   4    1      31         31
5   5    2      NA         15
6   6    2      NA         15
7   7    2      15         15
8   8    3      18         18
9   9    3      16         18
```

If you want to capture the last value, you can do :

```
ddply(df, .(user), transform, firstValue=tail(na.omit(columnB),1))
```

Comment: I think you could use `na.omit(columnB)[1]` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Ah yes, it's much nicer. Edited. Thanks !

Comment: probably you should replace `[1]` with `first(.)` from the `TTR` package as the OP was asking for using this function.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll give it a try tomorrow. And I'll try it using the first(.) and last(.).

Comment: @Arun: fair enough, but I suspect that `first` and `last` in the `TTR` package predated `head` and `tail` in base-R; also, if one is using a vector I can see how `tail(x)` is nice sugar for `x[length(x)]`, but `head(x)` isn't much better than `x[1]` (the main advantage of `first`/`head` is their generality)

Comment: @BenBolker I agree. I wrote it only because OP specifically asked for it.

Comment: I appreciate your response, however, I tried this but I was getting the correct values duplicated all into one cell for EACH user. It was a little strange for me. And the real data frame had about 10k+ users, so it actually crashed my R session and I lost all of my work lol. But it might have been something wrong with how I formatted it. This was just a miniature example of my real data frame. So there was probably some error on my part replacing your code with my variables. But like I said, I appreciate it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`

```
library (data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key="user")
DT <- setnames(DT[unique(DT[!is.na(columnB), list(columnB), by="user"])], "columnB.1", "first")
```

Comment: No, I'm on my iPhone.  No bueno? what happened? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, I didn't get a chance to try this because the second attempt was using Arun's solution. But it looks similar to his. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Using a very small helper function

```
finite <- function(x) x[is.finite(x)]
```

here is an one-liner using only standard R functions:

```
df <- cbind(df, firstValue = unlist(sapply(unique(df[,1]), function(user) rep(finite(df[df[,1] == user,2])[1], sum(df[,1] == user))))
```

For a better overview, here is the one-liner unfolded into a "multi-liner":

```
# for each user, find the first finite (in this case non-NA) value of the second column and replicate it as many times as the user has rows
# then, the results of all users are joined into one vector (unlist) and appended to the data frame as column
df <- cbind(
  df,
  firstValue = unlist(
    sapply(
       unique(df[,1]),
       function(user) {
         rep(
           finite(df[df[,1] == user,2])[1],
           sum(df[,1] == user)
         )
       }
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: why do you check for `is.finite` instead of `is.na`? this would exclude `NaN`, `Inf` etc.. including `NA`, which may not be desirable..

Comment: it's always nice to have the base-R example for comparison, but the relative complexity of the solution does show the advantages of `plyr` and `data.table` by contrast ...

Comment: you could also use `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(...),FUN))` to replicate the `plyr` approach.

Comment: @Arun Yes, this is true. I implicitly assumed that the OP was looking for a way to find the first actual number for each user. If this is not desired, just change `is.finite` to `!is.na`