# Mutate dplyr to select first value of a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
test<-data.frame(x=c(100,100,101,101,102,102),y=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),z=c(NA,NA,0.1,NA,NA,0.5))
```

I want to group by x. Then create a new variable ynew where I would look at z and select the first value that is not NA and then set ynew=y. If both values in z are NA then I would like ynew to be NA. ynew should be NA,NA,1,1,2,2. I am trying to do this using dplyr.

I am stuck with the following

```
group_by(test,x) %>% mutate(ynew=ifelse(all(is.na(z)),NA_integer_,y[corresponding index]))
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070213/skip-na-values-using-fun-first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following dplyr approach works if `test` is a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(test)

test %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(ynew = first(y[!is.na(z)]))

# Source: local data table [6 x 4]

#      x     y     z  ynew
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1   100     1    NA    NA
#2   100     2    NA    NA
#3   101     1   0.1     1
#4   101     2    NA     1
#5   102     1    NA     2
#6   102     2   0.5     2
```

Or you can simply use the `data.table` way

```
test[, ynew := y[!is.na(z)], x]
```

Comment: If is simple to explain, why do i need to convert the catedrales to data.tabla?

Comment: apperently *dplyr* doesn't handle subsetting within it's functions very well (see also [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637206/dplyr-n-distinct-with-condition/34637819#comment57020872_34637206))

Comment: Looks like this does not work with dplyr 0.5.x. I get the following error: Error: Unsupported vector type language